# Piping image on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pipe

Running this command in Windows shell:

```
djpeg -pnm -gray text.jpg | gocr -
```

works as expected - the image is decoded by `djpeg` executable and passed to `gocr` which decodes the contents.

I would like to run similar to this task under Python - pipe PIL image to `gocr` without writing temp files. For example I can instruct PIL to write the image in PPM format (accepted by `gocr` executable) to stdin:

```
im.save(sys.stdin, 'PPM')
```

but anything I tried with pipes and subprocess module, gives me no joy.

Can someone suggest how to run this task through Python - pipe image from PIL to executable and get the text output from stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to `gocr` subprocess' stdin, you could use `subprocess` module:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(["gocr", "-"], stdin=PIPE)
im.save(p.stdin, 'PPM')
p.stdin.close()
p.wait()
```

If `im.save()` doesn't work with a pipe then convert the image to a bytestring first:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from StringIO import StringIO

buf = StringIO()
im.save(buf, 'PPM')

p = Popen(["gocr", "-"], stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(input=buf.getvalue())
```

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate answer :) Both your snippets work great